# Can I join two queries together in a Stored procedure on Redshift?

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

Originally I was trying this with a function but to no avail. Redshift doesn't allow for table return types or select data from tables. I'm hoping that maybe there is a way to do this with a Stored procedure, but I don't have much confidence any more.  I have created a SP for the code listed below is it possible two join the two queries to itself for the SP?

tried doing a function, can't happen I have read the slim documentation that Amazon has for SPs and didn't get an answer for what I'm looking for

```
YTD current year
select 
   year
  , month
  , revenue
  ,transactiondate
  , Flag
from (
select
  extract(year from transactiondate) as year
  , to_char(transactiondate, 'Mon') as month
  , extract(month from transactiondate) as month_number
  , sum(netamount) as revenue
  ,transactiondate
  ,Flag
from
  vw_costs_of_businesss_copy

--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ->=  concat(to_char(extract(year from '2019-01-01'), 'YYYY'),'01-01') --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))),'01-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(Cas(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as text ),'-01-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(Cast(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as Text),'0000'),'-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')>= to_date(concat(to_char(Cast(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as Text),'0000'),'-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD')

group by
  year
  , month
  , month_number
  ,transactiondate
 , Flag
)
order by month_number, year

--YTD PREV YEAR
select 
   year
  , month
  , revenue
  ,transactiondate
  , Flag
from (
select
  extract(year from transactiondate) as year
  , to_char(transactiondate, 'Mon') as month
  , extract(month from transactiondate) as month_number
  , sum(netamount) as revenue
  ,transactiondate
  ,Flag
from
  vw_costs_of_businesss_copy

--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ->=  concat(to_char(extract(year from '2019-01-01'), 'YYYY'),'01-01') --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))),'01-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(Cas(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as text ),'-01-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(Cast(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as Text),'0000'),'-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')>= to_date(concat(to_char(Cast(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')-1) as Text),'0000'),'-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD')

group by
  year
  , month
  , month_number
  ,transactiondate
 , Flag
)

order by month_number, year
```

It needs to have the YTD and prev_YTD listed so I can pass it as a param, is this possible?  I realize I'd have to make a table for it to do so.
Where do I place the Prev_year, Prev-month columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the concept of [`UNION ALL`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_example_unionall_query.html) to "join the two queries".

Here is an example using a Stored Procedure. See ["Overview of Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html) for more info.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ytd_comparison(
      date_param IN    DATE
    , result_set INOUT REFCURSOR) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN result_set FOR --YTD
    SELECT year , month , revenue , transactiondate , Flag
    FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM transactiondate) AS year
               , TO_CHAR(transactiondate, 'Mon') AS month
               , EXTRACT(month FROM transactiondate) AS month_number
               , SUM(netamount) AS revenue
               , transactiondate
               , Flag
          FROM vw_costs_of_businesss_copy
          WHERE TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= date_param
            AND TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= DATE_TRUNC('year',date_param)
          GROUP BY year , month , month_number , transactiondate , Flag
          )
    UNION ALL --YTD PREV YEAR
    SELECT year ,month ,revenue ,transactiondate ,Flag
    FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM transactiondate) AS year
               , TO_CHAR(transactiondate, 'Mon') AS month
               , EXTRACT(month FROM transactiondate) AS month_number
               , SUM(netamount) AS revenue
               , transactiondate
               , Flag
          FROM vw_costs_of_businesss_copy
          WHERE TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= DATEADD(year, -1, date_param)
            AND TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= DATE_TRUNC('year', DATEADD(year, -1, date_param))
          GROUP BY year , month , month_number , transactiondate , Flag
          )
    ORDER BY month_number , year
    ;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You need to provide a name for the output `REFCURSOR` when calling the procedure. You must open a transaction with `BEGIN` to maintain the cursor, then fetch the output from the `REFCURSOR`, and then discard the results cursor with `END` transaction.

```sql
BEGIN;
CALL ytd_comparison ('2016-07-01'::DATE, 'ytd_results'); 
FETCH ALL FROM ytd_results; 
END;
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Alternatively, you could create a view for just the previous day.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ytd_comparison AS
SELECT year , month , revenue , transactiondate , Flag
FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM transactiondate) AS year
           , TO_CHAR(transactiondate, 'Mon') AS month
           , EXTRACT(month FROM transactiondate) AS month_number
           , SUM(netamount) AS revenue
           , transactiondate
           , Flag
      FROM vw_costs_of_businesss_copy
      WHERE TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= GETDATE() - 1
        AND TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= DATE_TRUNC('year',GETDATE() - 1)
      GROUP BY year , month , month_number , transactiondate , Flag
      )
UNION ALL --YTD PREV YEAR
SELECT year ,month ,revenue ,transactiondate ,Flag
FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM transactiondate) AS year
           , TO_CHAR(transactiondate, 'Mon') AS month
           , EXTRACT(month FROM transactiondate) AS month_number
           , SUM(netamount) AS revenue
           , transactiondate
           , Flag
      FROM vw_costs_of_businesss_copy
      WHERE TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE() - 1)
        AND TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= DATE_TRUNC('year', DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE() - 1))
      GROUP BY year , month , month_number , transactiondate , Flag
      )
ORDER BY month_number , year
;
```

Comment: question from this point is it possible to make this a view or table?

Comment: To make it a view or table you would have to calculate the values for every single possible day and then filter for just the day you want at query time. Would probably be better to use a prepared statement if a stored procedure is unsuitable. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PREPARE.html

Comment: I only need it for up to the current day as well as for the past two years YTD and current month.  However, looking at the prepare statement, i need to pass the values from the result set that the SP you re-worked gave me.

Comment: In that case, yes, you could do it as view quite easily. Added example to the answer.

Comment: dude your the best.  Sometimes its ant hill we make outta mountains, but for the life of me I could figure out how to do it.  really really appreciate your help!!